# Breakpoints not being hit in javascript function of aspx page VS2012

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

In VS2010 there was no issue with javascript breakpoints. Now that we are on VS2012, if I set a breakpoint in a javascript function that resides in the aspx page, the dubugger skips past it. Also, the aspx page is not showing up in the (Script Documents) of the solution while in debug mode. I thought I would be able to set a break point there, but not so much. Anyone having a similar issue and how can we fix this?

Comment: put debugger;  inside where you want to break

Comment: @DanHunex that worked for what i need. Thanks. Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put debugger; inside where you want to break as in

```
   function foo()
{
   debugger;

  //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Make sure you remove them too before promoting your code to production.